# Vertx: How to get fail() status code in failure handler?

Tags: error-handling, vert.x

**How can status code passed to [`RoutingContext.fail(int)`](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/RoutingContext.html#fail-int-) be retrieved in failure handler (registered using [`Route.failureHandler`](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/Route.html#failureHandler-io.vertx.core.Handler-))?**

E.g. If processing of some route takes too long, it can be interrupted by `TimeoutHandler` that calls `fail(408)` on `RoutingContext`. `fail` method subsequently invokes failure handler (if registered). However I can't find any way (except for reflection & depending on implementation) how to find out in handler itself why it was called:

- `RoutingContext.failure()` returns `null`
- status code seems to be set only in private field of `RoutingContextImpl`, not yet in `HttpServerResponse`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see the error code as there is a unit test for that specific scenario:

```
router.route(path).handler(rc -> {
  rc.fail(400);
}).failureHandler(frc -> {
  assertEquals(400, frc.statusCode());
  frc.response().setStatusCode(400).setStatusMessage("oh dear").end();
});
```

How are you registering your handler? and failure handler?

Comment: Using `Route.handler()` and `Route.failureHandler()`, exactly as in your example.

Comment: According to the test this should work, for the sake of completion what version are you using? Please be aware that 3.3.0 is to be out in a few days

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about older version of Vert.x, but from 3.0.0 an up:

```
eventBus.send("some.address", "some value", event -> {
  if (event.succeeded()) {
    System.out.println("Received reply: " + event.result().body());
  } else {
    ReplyException cause = (ReplyException) event.cause();
    String failMessage = cause.getMessage();
    int failCode = cause.failureCode();
  }
});
```